# Group By Three columns doesn't work in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by

I needed a result with Group By three columns and the SQL works perfectly without any issue. I'm facing the issue when I use it in the CodeIgniter framework; it doesn't execute the query. My Code and SQL are as follows.

**Code**

```
$this->db->select(['trk.userid AS user_id', 'scr.course AS course_id'])
                     ->from('mdl_scorm scr')
                     ->join('mdl_scorm_scoes_track trk', 'scr.id = trk.scormid', 'inner')
                     ->join('mdl_course_modules mcs', 'mcs.instance = scr.id', 'inner')
                     ->where_in('trk.value', ['completed','incomplete','passed'])
                     ->group_by(['scr.course', 'trk.userid', 'trk.scormid'])
                     ->order_by('trk.userid', 'DESC');
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT `trk`.`userid` AS user_id, `scr`.`course` AS course_id 
FROM (`mdl_scorm` scr) 
INNER JOIN `mdl_scorm_scoes_track` trk ON `scr`.`id` = `trk`.`scormid` INNER JOIN `mdl_course_modules` mcs ON `mcs`.`instance` = `scr`.`id` 
WHERE `trk`.`value` IN ('completed', 'incomplete', 'passed') 
GROUP BY `scr`.`course`, `trk`.`userid`, `trk`.`scormid` 
ORDER BY `trk`.`userid` DESC LIMIT 0,100;
```

This works fine when the group_by has only two columns, like,

```
->group_by(['scr.course', 'trk.userid'])
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **In codeigniter `group_by()` works *with two fields* only.**

---

**`$this->db->group_by()`**

Permits you to write the **GROUP BY** portion of your query:

```
$this->db->group_by(array("title", "date"));  // Produces: GROUP BY title, date
```

[CI 3 `group_by()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)

---

**Edit 01**

```
$query=$this->db->query("
        SELECT `trk`.`userid` AS user_id, `scr`.`course` AS course_id 
        FROM `mdl_scorm` scr 
        INNER JOIN `mdl_scorm_scoes_track` trk 
        ON `scr`.`id` = `trk`.`scormid` 
        INNER JOIN `mdl_course_modules` mcs 
        ON `mcs`.`instance` = `scr`.`id` 
        WHERE `trk`.`value` IN ('completed', 'incomplete', 'passed') 
        GROUP BY `scr`.`course`, `trk`.`userid`, `trk`.`scormid` 
        ORDER BY `trk`.`userid` 
        DESC LIMIT 0,100;");

$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: Thanks.
Documentation never mentioned on the limitation of field used in `group_by()`. In the documentation it says _You can also pass an array of multiple values as well:_

Comment: Actually the means only 2.

Comment: @Vaishak any comments??

Comment: I was trying what @Drew had suggested, using raw query. But that doesn't work either. The issue occurs at `$result = $query->result();` or even at `$result = $query->row_array();`

Comment: So the issue is not at the level of executing the query, but while retrieving the result, I guess.

Comment: Yes, tried the same too. Look at the value _$query_ returns.
`CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #2 [result_id] => Resource id #6 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 100 [row_data] => )` @Abdulla, @Drew

Comment: Could the memory limitation causing the issue?

Basically, when we use group_by, it should reduce the number of columns right?

eg: When I used `GROUP BY scr.course, trk.userid` result was ~25 and when used `GROUP BY scr.course, trk.userid, trk.scormid` result came about double!!

Answer (score 3):

Consider a raw query in the model.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class xyz_model extends CI_Model{
     function __construct()
     {
          // Call the Model constructor
          parent::__construct();
     }

     function get_this_thing($month,$year) 
     {    $myQuery="SELECT `trk`.`userid` AS user_id, `scr`.`course` AS course_id 
          FROM `mdl_scorm` scr 
          INNER JOIN `mdl_scorm_scoes_track` trk 
          ON `scr`.`id` = `trk`.`scormid` 
          INNER JOIN `mdl_course_modules` mcs 
          ON `mcs`.`instance` = `scr`.`id` 
          WHERE `trk`.`value` IN ('completed', 'incomplete', 'passed') 
          GROUP BY `scr`.`course`, `trk`.`userid`, `trk`.`scormid` 
          ORDER BY `trk`.`userid` 
          DESC LIMIT 0,100;";

          $query = $this->db->query($myQuery);

          $result = $query->result();
          return $result;
     }
}
```

Comment: No. This doesn't work either. The code stops at `$result = $query->result();`

Comment: what table sizing are we talking about. I know queries from some people that run for an hour. That is how I meet them. I am going on the fact that your query works before you come in here talking about 3 columns in the group by, or trying to get a `raw` to work that otherwise would be tricky or impossible with CI

Comment: It was due to memory limitation, I wasn't able to get the expected result, I guess. I had to tweak the query and memory/cache limit to get expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass an array of multiple values as well:

```
$this->db->group_by(array("title", "date"));  // Produces: GROUP BY title, date
```

[Source link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

use result array instead of the result like

```
return $query->result_array();
```